# CSS TranslateY Causing item to rotate

Tags: css, translate-animation

I'm trying to cause an element to move down and fade in once the page loads. Here is my html:

```
<h1 class="home-title animate">Hello</h1>
```

And my CSS:

```
h1 {
font-family: 'Sentinel A', 'Sentinel B', sans-serif!important;
font-weight: 300;
text-transform: inherit;
color: #2e2e2e;
margin-top: 100px;
font-size: 4rem;
line-height: 1.2;
margin: 2rem 0 2.5rem;
}

.home-title {
-webkit-animation-duration: .9s;
animation-duration: .9s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-fill-mode: both;
-webkit-animation-delay: .9s;
animation-delay: .9s;
}
.animate {
-webkit-animation-name: animate;
animation-name: animate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
}
100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
}
}
@keyframes animate {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-40px);
}
100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
}
}
```

This seems to work ok in codepen, yet when it's on my site the words start off with a 1 opacity and rotate 90 degrees so the beginning of the word is pointed towards the top of the screen and then the animation stops.

Comment: If it works on codepen but not your site I'm thinking there are conflicting styles.

Comment: Any idea how i can figure out what's causing it? I used the same thing on three different properties and they all do the same thing. It's so odd

Comment: Have you simply inspected thge element to see the applied styles? If thats not it, move up the DOM tree until you find the element that causing it.